# hammer.js object has no method addEventListener

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I am getting the Error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addEventListener' hammer.js:168`

my code is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hammer.js"></script>
```

On device ready function:

```
 var resim = $('#kaydir');

 Hammer(resim).on('swipeleft', function(ev){
     console.log('left: ', ev);
 });
```

It seems the error is in hammer.js . What should I do?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I imagine your issue is that you don't have [Hammer.js's jQuery Plugin](http://hammerjs.github.io/jquery-plugin/) installed ([GitHub](https://github.com/hammerjs/jquery.hammer.js)).

Because of this, you cannot pass a jQuery object into the `Hammer()` function, your two options:

### With the jQuery Plugin

Add the jQuery Plugin I've linked to above to your project, then call:

```
$('#kaydir').Hammer(...)
```

### Without the jQuery Plugin

Pass only the element into `Hammer()` and not the jQuery object, by using `[0]`:

```
Hammer(resim[0]).on(...)
```

Or instead change your `resim` variable to hold the result of calling JavaScript's `getElementById`.

```
var resim = document.getElementById('kaydir');
Hammer(resim).on(...)
```

Comment: I downvoted you for "Based on the information provided in the identical question you deleted yesterday..."  What is the purpose of that?

Comment: @Andre Bulatov this answer was based on information provided in the previous question. Without it, this answer would be nothing more than speculation.

Comment: Hammer(resim[0]).on(...) its working great but what to do when I need to apply on all elements in     resim??

Comment: @maddy use a loop. `for (var i = 0; i < resim.length; i++) { Hammer(resim[i]]).on(...) }`

Comment: @JamesDonnelly But I am getting another problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38101901/jquery-functions-not-working-with-hammer-js

Comment: @JamesDonnelly When using jQuery Plugin you should use the lower case ".hammer" ("$(...).hammer(...)" instead of  "$(...).Hammer(...)") because it leads to error "$(...).Hammer is not a function" in Google Chrome otherwise.

Comment: Passing a jQuery object to Hammer() doesn't work regardless of hammer's jQuery plugin pulled or not. But passing only element as in answer eg. `a=new Hammer($('.test')[0])` worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using jQuery, you should use the [jQuery Hammer version](http://hammerjs.github.io/jquery-plugin/) and use it like that:

```
var resim = $("#kaydir");
resim.hammer().on("swipeleft", function(ev) {
    console.log('left: ', ev);
});
```