# jQuery functions not working with Hammer.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

I am trying to add `press` to jQuery selector. I have many elements on same document, So I can not use IDs for each. I tried by `$(selector)[i]` as like explained **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28191732/hammer-js-object-has-no-method-addeventlistener/28191816?noredirect=1#comment63628392_28191816)**.

```
var selectProduct = $('.mh60 a');
for (var i = 0; i < selectProduct.length; i++) {
  Hammer(selectProduct[i]).on("press", function() {
     $(selectProduct[i]).addClass('active');
  });
}
```

It's not producing any error and not working. I didn't get what I am missing here.

And when I try to log `selectProduct[i]` by `console.log(selectProduct[i]);` it gives `undefined` result.

**UPDATE 1**

When I remove for loop and just use `selectProduct[0]` , `selectProduct[1]` , ... it's working but with `selectProduct[i]` , it's not working, So I think problem is on for loop. But I didn't get it.

**UPDATE 2**

I also tried with [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/hammerjs/jquery.hammer.js), same problem

**UPDATE 3**

Again I tried with `each()`, same problem. It print the console message but `addClass()` is not working. I guess the problem is with `this` function which is not returning the current element.

```
$('.mh60 a').each(function(){
    var mc = new Hammer(this);
    mc.on("press", function() {
      console.log('Double tap!');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem by using `each` function

```
$('.mh60 a').each(function(){
    var mc = new Hammer(this);
    var currentEle = $(this);
    mc.on("press", function() {
      currentEle.addClass('active');
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use a for?
Try changing your code like this

```
var selectProduct = $('.mh60 a');
selectProduct.Hammer().on("press", function() {
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: hammer.min.js:6Uncaught TypeError: a.addEventListener is not a function

Comment: instead of using jquery selector, try with pure js one

Comment: I tried same error, you can also check another question linked on this question, may be you get something

Comment: If you jquery Hammer, have you tried with `selectProduct.Hammer().on(...)` ?

Comment: you mean like this ?    selectProduct.Hammer.on("press", function() {..});    same problem

Comment: I used Hammer once and i hadn't these problems... I'm sorry i couldn't help you :(