# conflict between hammer.js and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hammer

I am trying to create a swipe effect with help of hammer.js but it seems it creating a issue with jquery file

jquery code with hammer

```
       $( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );

        $(".swiper").hammer().on("swipeleft", function(event) {
    //callback

     console.log( "swipeleft!" );

});
});
```

html code

error

[image]

Comment: Which version of hammer.js have you included in your HTML?

Comment: Did you include all the necessary files in your HTML?

Comment: Finally I found a solution in Stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38101901/jquery-functions-not-working-with-hammer-js

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have already included hammer.js and jQuery in your project. You can try this now.

```
var hammer = new Hammer($(".swiper")[0]);
hammer.on("swipeLeft", function(evt){
console.log("Swipe Left");
});
```

Comment: i am not getting the console.log("Swipe Left");

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pmpmvwry/1/   hammer will not work in jsfiddle as it is without https

Comment: You can check this.
Try swiping on first 'li' element. It works fine.
https://jsfiddle.net/pmpmvwry/2/

Comment: but its does not work for all, As you have added a array number, how to make it to work all

Comment: You need to pass a JS DOM element to hammer constructor (not jQuery object). That's why I am passing first 'li' element. If you want to apply swipe on all 'li' elements, better use 'ul' element instead of 'li'.
For more info, check this 
http://hammerjs.github.io/getting-started/